# JS blend out table column when checkbox is checked

Tags: javascript, jquery, checkbox

i'm trying to hide/show table columns when a checkbox is checked or not. This is working but not really the way i need it. I need the checkboxes to stay checked after a form is submitted and the columns to stay

Thanks in advance for any help

This is what i've got so far

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>


<title>javascript test</title>

<meta charset="utf-8">

<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>

<style>
    table ,td ,th{
        border-collapse: collapse;
        border: 1px solid black;        
}
    td, th{
        min-width: 150px;
}
    th{
        padding: 15px;
}
    td{
        padding: 10px;
}
    body{
        font-family: arial;
}

</style>

<script>

$(document).ready(function() {
    $('input[type="checkbox"]').click(function() {
    var index = $(this).attr('name').substr(3);
    index--;
    $('table tr').each(function() { 
        $('td:eq(' + index + ')',this).toggle();
    });
    $('th.' + $(this).attr('name')).toggle();
    });
});

</script>

</head>

<body>



<form action="#" method="post">

    <input type="text" name="suche">
    <input type="submit" name="senden">

    <br/>
    <br/>

</form>

<form>

    <label>Spalte1<input type="checkbox" name="col1"></label>
    <label>Spalte2<input type="checkbox" name="col2"></label>
    <label>Spalte3<input type="checkbox" name="col3"></label>
    <label>Spalte4<input type="checkbox" name="col4"></label>
    <label>Spalte5<input type="checkbox" name="col5"></label>
    <label>Spalte6<input type="checkbox" name="col6"></label>

</form>

<br/>
<br/>

<table>

    <tr>
        <th class="col1">Spalte1</th>
        <th class="col2">Spalte2</th>
        <th class="col3">Spalte3</th>
        <th class="col4">Spalte4</th>
        <th class="col5">Spalte5</th>
        <th class="col6">Spalte6</th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Spalte1</td>
        <td>Spalte2</td>
        <td>Spalte3</td>
        <td>Spalte4</td>
        <td>Spalte5</td>
        <td>Spalte6</td>
    </tr>

</table>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: are you using a server side language

Comment: i'm on an ubuntu 16.04 machine with apache2 and php7.0 installed

Answer (score 0):

```
<form action="#" method="post" onsubmit="return false">
```

try `onsubmit="return false"`

Comment: but then i cant submit the form anymore

Comment: what do you mean?

Comment: $('#formName').submit(function () {
    console.log('submit');
   return false;
  });

try this

Comment: can you please be more specific where i need to put this code? i've put it below the script i already have and i've tried adding a script section in the form

Comment: still resets columns and checkboxes after i submit the form - thanks alot for your help btw

Answer (score 0):

You can use php to process the form values. At the top of the page we are setting some local variables if the value is passed from posting the form.

Then in the html we are setting the checked value, and setting the display property of the td elements so they will be hidden when the page loads.

#### setting checked property

```
<label>Spalte1<input type="checkbox" name="col1" <?=$col1?>></label>
```

#### setting display of td

```
<td<?php if($col1):?> class="display:none;"<?php endif?>>Spalte1</td>
```

I unfortunately have not got php installed on this computer, so hopefully there is no syntax errors as I cannot check.

```
<?php
    // if the post var is passed set local variables of the checkbox state
    $col1 = isset($_POST['col1']) ? 'checked' : '';
    $col2 = isset($_POST['col2']) ? 'checked' : '';
    $col3 = isset($_POST['col3']) ? 'checked' : '';
?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>javascript test</title>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>
<style>
table ,td ,th{
    border-collapse: collapse;
    border: 1px solid black;        
}
td, th{
    min-width: 150px;
}
th{
    padding: 15px;
}
td{
    padding: 10px;
}
body{
    font-family: arial;
}
</style>
<script>
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('input[type="checkbox"]').click(function() {
    var index = $(this).attr('name').substr(3);
    index--;
    $('table tr').each(function() { 
        $('td:eq(' + index + ')',this).toggle();
    });
    $('th.' + $(this).attr('name')).toggle();
    });
});
</script>
</head>
<body>
<form action="#" method="post">
    <input type="text" name="suche">
    <input type="submit" name="senden">
</form>

<form>
    <!-- set the checkbox state if it's available -->
    <label>Spalte1<input type="checkbox" name="col1" <?=$col1?>></label>
    <label>Spalte2<input type="checkbox" name="col2" <?=$col2?>></label>
    <label>Spalte3<input type="checkbox" name="col3" <?=$col3?>></label>
</form>

<table>
    <tr>
        <th class="col1">Spalte1</th>
        <th class="col2">Spalte2</th>
        <th class="col3">Spalte3</th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td<?php if($col1):?> class="display:none;"<?php endif?>>Spalte1</td>
        <td<?php if($col1):?> class="display:none;"<?php endif?>>Spalte2</td>
        <td<?php if($col1):?> class="display:none;"<?php endif?>>Spalte3</td>
    </tr>
</table>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: i've tried this code but it does not work the way i need it to. the columns and the checkbox are reset everytime i submit the form